# Sending scroll commands with SendInput on Windows10 UWP applications

Tags: c#, winapi, uwp, windows-10, sendinput

I have code very similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7182813/cant-send-new-scroll-direction-with-sendinput-in-lowlevelmouseproc-call) running in a windows tray application, even with this exact code from the question I get the same behavior. It all works well on classic windows applications, such as Firefox, Chrome, Windows Explorer etc. However when the mouse focus gets to a UWP app such as Edge or Calendar or Mail the scroll becomes jittery and after a few dozen scrolls performed my application hangs and can't even be terminated from task manager (permission denied), this behavior is very reproducible.

I'll paste the code from the question here:

```
using System;

using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace EnableMacScrolling
{
class InterceptMouse
{
    const int INPUT_MOUSE = 0;
    const int MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL = 0x0800;
    const int WH_MOUSE_LL = 14; 


    private static LowLevelMouseProc _proc = HookCallback;
    private static IntPtr _hookID = IntPtr.Zero;

    public static void Main()
    {
        _hookID = SetHook(_proc);

        if (_hookID == null)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("SetWindowsHookEx Failed");
            return;
        }
        Application.Run();
        UnhookWindowsHookEx(_hookID);
    }

    private static IntPtr SetHook(LowLevelMouseProc proc)
    {
        using (Process curProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
        using (ProcessModule curModule = curProcess.MainModule)
        {
            return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_MOUSE_LL, proc,
                GetModuleHandle(curModule.ModuleName), 0);
        }
    }

    private delegate IntPtr LowLevelMouseProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    private static IntPtr HookCallback(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam)
    {
        if (nCode >= 0 && MouseMessages.WM_MOUSEWHEEL == (MouseMessages)wParam)
        {
            MSLLHOOKSTRUCT hookStruct = (MSLLHOOKSTRUCT)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lParam, typeof(MSLLHOOKSTRUCT));

            Console.WriteLine(hookStruct.mouseData);
            if (hookStruct.flags != -1) //prevents recursive call to self
            {
                INPUT input;
                input = new INPUT();
                input.type = INPUT_MOUSE;
                input.mi.dx = 0;
                input.mi.dy = 0;
                input.mi.dwFlags = MOUSEEVENTF_WHEEL;
                input.mi.time = 0;
                input.mi.dwExtraInfo = 0;
                input.mi.mouseData = -(hookStruct.mouseData >> 16);
                try
                {
                   SendInput(1, ref input, Marshal.SizeOf(input));
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }

                return (IntPtr)1;
            }
        }
        return CallNextHookEx(_hookID, nCode, wParam, lParam);
    }


    private enum MouseMessages
    {
        WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct POINT
    {
        public int x;
        public int y;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    private struct MSLLHOOKSTRUCT
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public int mouseData;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public IntPtr dwExtraInfo;
    }

    public struct INPUT
    {
        public int type;
        public MOUSEINPUT mi;
    }

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct MOUSEINPUT
    {
        public int dx;
        public int dy;
        public int mouseData;
        public uint dwFlags;
        public int time;
        public int dwExtraInfo;
    }



    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook,
        LowLevelMouseProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    private static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode,
        IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    private static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);

    [DllImport("User32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern int SendInput(int nInputs, ref INPUT pInputs, int cbSize);

} }
```

Is it possible that I'm dealing with a bug in windows here? Any pointers to how I can find out what's going on?

**Update:**

I have created a test Win32 application in C++ to more easily reproduce/demonstrate the problem. The issue is with the SendCommand which when executed while any classic application is in focus works fine. However when executed while a UWP application is in focus, or even the windows launch/start menu causes the calling application (my application) to hang and be stuck until windows is restarted.

An effective workaround/solution for this problem is to perform the SendCommand call on another thread from the thread handling the hook callback. Immediately launching the thread that executes SendCommand and returning from the hook callback produces the desired behavior and doesn't cause any problems.

Comment: @hatchet I am aware of this. My application is not UWP, it is a classic desktop app.

Comment: This may be an issue related to the 32/64 bit issue of SetWindowsHookEx. You may get around it by creating a second thread, and running SetWindowsHookEx in the context of that thread. See the discussion of 32/64 and message pump: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644990(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Where is your C++ sample app?

Answer (score 4):

```
if (hookStruct.flags != -1) //prevents recursive call to self
```

That's rather important, yes.  But how the statement could possibly do its job is very unclear.  The expected value of this field is 0, 1 or 3.  Never -1.  You perhaps got mislead by another mouse hook that is active on your machine.

Now it does matter whether a WinRT app is in the foreground.  Because then the message broker is involved and the field value changes, the [LLMHF_LOWER_IL_INJECTED bit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644970(v=vs.85).aspx) is turned on.  WinRT apps run in a sandbox that run at a lower integrity level.  So the field will not be -1 and your SendInput() call triggers the mouse hook again.  On and on it goes, show is over when it runs out of stack.

So first possible fix is to use the field as intended, change the statement to:

```
if ((hookStruct.flags & 1) == 0)
```

Won't work if that presumed wonky mouse hook is corrupting the field, then consider using a `static` bool field in your class to break the recursion.  Set it to *true* before the SendInput() call, *false* afterwards.

---

But I think I know why you are doing this, I too have been a victim of a trackpad that got it backwards.  There is a much easier way to do it, just modify the [FlipFlopWheel setting](https://superuser.com/questions/310681/inverting-direction-of-mouse-scroll-wheel).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually It's not getting into recursion. I've checked this. My code is different from the example and for a different purpose than inverting the scroll altogether. But this example causes the same problem. Either with my condition or yours, the SendCommand call is causing the problem after a few executions, not at the first execution.

Comment: Sigh, why are you wasting my free time with code you don't actually use and a reason you refuse to document??  It is not free, I could help somebody else.  And no, it does not cause a problem after a "few executions", blowing the stack of the operating system takes more than that.